# Failed to instantiate one or more classes : In XML preview ,custom view is Rendered in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-custom-view, koin

In Android Studio, XML is not rendered for the custom view.

Android Studio: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

how to render the custom view in XML preview. It gives the following error.

I already tried all of these solutions but it does not work for me

-File/Invalidate Caches/Restart.

- `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72"`
- 

```
android {
...
    kotlinOptions {
...
        freeCompilerArgs = [
                "-Xno-optimized-callable-references"
        ]
    }
}
```

```
Failed to instantiate one or more classes

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.custom.views.base.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.

If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout. 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Koin Context configured. Please use startKoin or koinApplication DSL. 
    at org.koin.core.context.KoinContextHandler.getContext(KoinContextHandler.kt:29)
    at org.koin.core.context.KoinContextHandler.get(KoinContextHandler.kt:35)
    at org.koin.core.KoinComponent$DefaultImpls.getKoin(KoinComponent.kt:32)
    at com.example.presentation.custom.themable.Themable$DefaultImpls.getKoin(Themable.kt)
    at com.example.presentation.custom.views.base.ProgressBar.getKoin(ProgressBar.kt:14)
    at com.example.presentation.custom.themable.Themable$DefaultImpls.getTheme(Themable.kt:55)
    at com.example.presentation.custom.views.base.ProgressBar.getTheme(ProgressBar.kt:14)
    at com.example.presentation.custom.views.base.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.kt:24)
    at com.example.presentation.custom.views.base.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.kt:18)
    at com.example.presentation.custom.views.base.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:351)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:359)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:$ use latest version'
implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:$ use latest version'
```

Comment: Peer Mohamed, It's already added, still not working for me.